How to add extra stuff to a cherry-pick?
When cherry-picking in git, I have often the situation that I want to add extra changes to it like a ChangeLog or NEWS entry.
When the cherry-pick stops with a conflict, then everything is fine: I am fixing the conflicts, add the extra bits, then git add, git cherry-pick --cont etc.
However when the cherry-pick does not come up with a conflict it gets annoying:
$ git cherry-pick -x <ref> # Passes fine
$ git reset --soft HEAD~1
$ git add ... # My extra bits
$ git commit -c HEAD@{1}

Is there a simpler way to make cherry-pick stop? I tried --no-commit but then I don't get the cherry-pick generated commit message and author.

No need for reset. Just add and amend:
$ git cherry-pick -x <ref> # Passes fine
$ git add ... # My extra bits
$ git commit --amend --no-edit


Oh, it's really that easy?! Thanks.

@emacsdrivesmenuts Even better: git commit --amend --no-edit to avoid editing commit message.
